# Filter object by 2 or more strings

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have 2 objects, a course list and a user.

The course list is an array with a lot of courses:

```
[
  {
    "id": 12345,
    "title": "Some title",
    "type": [
      {
        "id": 4700,
        "slug": "someType",
        "name": "someTypeName"
      }
    ],
    "difficulty": [
      {
        "id": 4704,
        "slug": "4",
        "name": "hard"
      }
    ],..
  },
{...}
```

The user have also some fields:

```
{
  "difficulty": 4, // the difficulty->slug
  "type": "someType"  // the type->slug
}
```

**My task:**

I want to find the best match between the courses and the user.

In this example the user is looking for `type.slug == someType` and a `difficulty.slug == 4`. The slug is always the search term.

My first attempt was:

```
courseList.filter((course) => {
    if (course.type.indexOf(that.userData.type) != -1) {
        return course; // dont work
    }
});
```

**Edit:** I need to display the `name` and the `id` properties in the front-end  and the "slug" is always the search term.

Comment: More explanations needed. Why are `type` and `difficulty` arrays?

Comment: basically i need the "name" and the "id" in the frontend to display them and the "slug" is always the search term.

Comment: Not answering my question. The element `type` (and `difficulty` too) is an array, so given 1 course id you can have more than one type. That seems strange, and I don't understand the reason of this design

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `filter` function takes a `function` (in your case the `arrow` function) that returns a `boolean` so try this instead:

```
var filterredList = courseList.filter(course => {
     return course.type.filter(type => type.slug == that.userData.type).length > 0 
         && course.difficulty.filter(difficulty => difficulty.slug == that.userData.difficulty).length > 0
});
```

Comment: this dont work, i need some kind of interator for course.type.slug

I could use course.type[0].slug, but i need all courses with a particular type.

Comment: The `filter` function itself iterates through the whole list

Comment: @Fargho I have updated the answer's code to use a more compact version of it

Comment: But course.type is an array of objects? there is no slug?

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was a `json`, I will update the answer.

Comment: @Fargho the answer is updated to deal with `course.type` as an array. And I suggest to edit the name to `types` instead.

Comment: Wow, awesome! Thanks! there is a "return" missing but it works fine! 

Yep, good idea. "type" is not a good value name.

Comment: @styfle the OP was asking for a demo on one of them, and then he applied on the other.

Comment: @styfle I updated the answer to include the difficulty check.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare the `slug` properties against the user data.

The trick here is to make sure you are filtering the arrays and checking the count.

```js
var courseList = [
  {
    "id": 12345,
    "title": "Some title",
    "type": [
      {
        "id": 4700,
        "slug": "someType",
        "name": "someTypeName"
      }
    ],
    "difficulty": [
      {
        "id": 4704,
        "slug": "4",
        "name": "hard"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 12346,
    "title": "Another title",
    "type": [
      {
        "id": 4701,
        "slug": "anotherType",
        "name": "anotherTypeName"
      }
    ],
    "difficulty": [
      {
        "id": 4704,
        "slug": "4",
        "name": "hard"
      }
    ]
  }
];
  
var userData = {
  type: 'someType',
  difficulty: 4
};
  
  
var filteredList = courseList.filter(o =>
  o.type.filter(t => t.slug === userData.type).length > 0
  && o.difficulty.filter(d => d.slug === userData.difficulty.toString()).length > 0
);


// Print just the titles of the filtered list
console.log(filteredList.map(o => o.title));
```